# How can i extract only time from the json field using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

i have a json of time:

```
  "opening_hours": {
    "monday": "closed",
    "tuesday": "10 - 13 + 14:30 - 18.30",
    "wednesday": "10 - 13 + 14:30 - 18.30",
    "thursday": "10 - 13 + 14:30 - 18.30",
    "friday": "10 - 13 + 14: 30 - 18.30",
    "saturday": "10:00 - 14:00 (Dez. bis 1600.0000)",
    "sunday": "closed"
  },
```

i have to extract the time from the json.

i'm using this code (regex):

```
for day in row['opening_hours']:
        re.findall(r'\d{1,2}[:.]\d{2}|\d{1,2}', row['opening_hours'][day])
```

```
\d{1,2} ----- for 09:00 or 9:00
[:.] -------- for checking either : or .
\d{2} ------------ for :30
|\d{1,2}  --------------- for 06 or 6
```

but if you see there is space in friday "14: 30" how can i ignore these spaces in between the time.

Also I cannot use replace() because there are few places, where instead of time, there is a text sentence and i cannot replace spaces between those sentence.

So is there any way that i could just ignore it with the regex code.

expected output:

```
['10' , '13' , '14: 30' , '18.30'].
```

even after that.i need to convert this time into

```
['10:00' , '13:00' , '14:30' , '18:30']
```

but thats a later process .

Comment: And why would you want `regex` to parse `JSON`? Show [mre], incl. valid sample, and expected output.

Comment: `how can i ignore these spaces in between the time.` - you can pre-process your dict to remove any inconsistencies or just all spaces if you're not sure if this won't happen again with other data (what if you get `18 : 30` later?). As for space that might be here but you're not sure - read about what `?` means in regex

Comment: @buran actually the json is sent from client , i have to convert it into my json according to database and i cannot store date in this format .

Comment: @h4z3 that's why i'm asking to help me modify this data and ignore spaces which are in between the time . and it is just a one time process . so i will not get any file later on.

Comment: If you parse/deserialize JSON properly, usieng `json` module, the value for `"opening_hours"` key will become python dict where days will be keys and working hours will be values of type `str`. Now, that is what the question is - what output expect to get? E.g. what for Monday-Friday, what for Saturday, what for Sunday?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if i ignore the friday time . for other i'm getting ```['10' , '13' , '14:30',  '18.30']```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew . ```['10' , '13' , '14: 30' , '18.30']```. even after that. i need to convert this time into ```['10:00' , '13:00' , '14:30' , '18:30']```. but thats a later process .

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the numbers as following:

To handle the notes (assuming they are always in parentheses!

```py
val = '8 - 9 + 10:00 - 14:00 (Dez. bis 1600.0000)'
time_end_idx = val.find("(")
val = val[:time_end_idx]
# '8 - 9 + 10:00 - 14:00 '
```

```py
day_time_slots = re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}[:.]?\d{,2})", val)
# ['8', '9', '10:00', '14:00']
```

Where val is the time string. You could then proceed to split it into pairs as opening/closing times for each day

```py
slots = [day_time_slots[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(day_time_slots), 2)]
# [['8', '9'], ['10:00', '14:00']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
(?<!\d)(\d{1,2})\d*\s?[:.-]\s?(\d{2})\d*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eep9Ng/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - left-hand numeric boundary
- `(\d{1,2})` - one or more digits
- `\d*` - any more digits if any
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `[:.-]` - `.`, `:` or `-` char
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `(\d{2})` - two digits
- `\d*` - zero or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0FLn9l):

```py
import re, json

row = {"opening_hours": {
    "monday": "closed",
    "tuesday": "10 - 13 + 14:30 - 18.30",
    "wednesday": "10 - 13 + 14:30 - 18.30",
    "thursday": "10 - 13 + 14:30 - 18.30",
    "friday": "10 - 13 + 14: 30 - 18.30",
    "saturday": "10:00 - 14:00 (Dez. bis 1600.0000)",
    "sunday": "closed"
}}

for day in row['opening_hours']:
    print([f'{x}:{y}' for x,y in re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,2})\d*\s?[:.-]\s?(\d{2})\d*', row['opening_hours'][day])])
```

Output:

```
[]
['10:13', '14:30', '18:30']
['10:13', '14:30', '18:30']
['10:13', '14:30', '18:30']
['10:13', '14:30', '18:30']
['10:00', '14:00', '16:00']
[]
```